# Is it possible to avoid sharing usage information with Microsoft?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, privacy

I recently opened Microsoft Excel 2016 and got the following pop-up:

[image: "Share how you use Office" dialogue window]

Neither option says "do not share my data", the only way I can seem to do that is to close the dialogue. The downside of that is that I have to do so every time I open an Office application.

My only way out seems to be to pick the "Basic" option and then go turn it off but I'm slightly concerned that turning it off won't really do so.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: If you use a competing product, like LibreOffice, none of your information will ever be shared with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no setting in Office to directly disable it. You can open the App menu, select **Preferences**, select **Security & Privacy**. You can then select your preference.

You can read the **Microsoft Privacy Statement** to know why they collect the data and how they deal with your personal data:
https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement